# alternative ways of stubbing collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor, stubbing

In [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), is there any way to stub a collection for unit testing without using [`hwillson:stub-collections`](https://atmospherejs.com/hwillson/stub-collections)? Using this package is unfortunately not an option due to package constraints (`mongo@1.0.11`), and neither is using a test Mongodb instance.

Comment: Have you checked the package content? It is not that complex, you could try to copy that behavior or fork and improve the package. I would even support you in that since I also rely on it and a mongo version upgrade would be great.

Comment: I'll try a fork in the meantime, and link you in.